# Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices Error: Discarding entity body for GET requests

Tags: angular, single-page-application, server-side-rendering, asp.net-core-1.1

Environment: asp.net core 1.1 + angular 4.2.3 +vs2017 15.3 preview 2

Server side rendering generated the following log:

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices[0]
Discarding entity body for GET requests

In Angular, I am making call to one Web API.

```
/**
 * Get endpoint for application configuration
 */
getAppConfigEndpoint(): Observable<Response> {
    let header = new Headers();
    header.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    return this.http.get(this.getFullUrl(Endpoints.API_URL_APP_CONFIGURATION), { headers: header });
}
```

From the message itself, it seems request body was added in a GET request. But I don't think that is case.

Anyone know anything about this issue? or the approach to debug for this scenario?

[Click Here to View Request Details of Server Side Rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5liy.png)

Comment: I have the same error but I actually get the data later on in `.subscribe()`. It seems as if it's not waiting for the data before rendering the application. I'm doing something similar to you but extending `Http` and using `return Observable.fromPromise()` and from there I return `super.get(url, requestOption)`. I'm extending `Http` to add same header to all calls. EDIT: It's not working for me either.